# Plotting with Sparkline in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, charts, stock, google-finance

I used the following formula to plot the stock value prices in Google Sheets using Google Finance.

```
sparkline(index(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",workday(TODAY(),-7),today()),,2),{"charttype","column";"color","green"})
```

The above gives 7 bars in the chart as intended for the stock "GOOG".

But when I use the same formula for an Indian stock "INFY", I get only 6 bars. I used the following.

```
sparkline(index(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:INFY","price",workday(TODAY(),-7),today()),,2),{"charttype","column";"color","green"})
```

I checked my settings and ensured the time zones and Locale to India.

What could be the reason for this different behavior?